# Add missing contents of one file to another

Tags: text-processing, files, scripting

```
FILE1=$1   
FILE2=$2

if [ ! -e "$FILE2" ]
then
   touch $FILE2
fi

while read line; do
  if grep -q "$line" $FILE2
  then
    echo
  else
    echo $line >> $FILE2
  fi
done < $FILE1
```

I want to add the lines of FILE1 to FILE2 if they are not present in FILE2. My purpose is to list FILE1's lines, and add them to FILE2 if the lines are not present in FILE2.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please give a better explanation of what your code is doing and what you actually expect it to do.

Comment: What makes you say something is wrong? I just tried your script, and the only thing weird about it is that your `echo` line causes a lot of blank output. Apart from that, it successfully copied missing lines from $1 into $2

Comment: You are looking for `comm`  `man comm`

Comment: Yes, we don't know what's 'wrong', but we assume either missed entries and/or duplicates.  For grep command to be more restrictive, thereby reducing duplicates, grep -x would match the whole line (not just part of it) excluding more matches. Alternately, grep -i might include more matches by ignoring case.  It's possible one or both might be appropriate.

Comment: echo in then clause should be replace by true (to avoid blank line), it may not work with many word in a line in FILE1.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR == FNR {first[$0];next}; ! ($0 in first)' "$file2" "$file1" >> "$file2"
```

That assumes that the file names don't contain `=` characters. If they might, on systems that support /dev/fd/n, you could do:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {first[$0];next}; ! ($0 in first)' \
  /dev/fd/3 3< "$file2" /dev/fd/4 4< "$file1" >> "$file2"
```

Note that if lines occur several times in `$file1` and not in `$file2`, all occurrences will be appended to `$file2`. If that's not what you want, then:

```
awk 'NR != FNR && ! ($0 in seen); {seen[$0]}' \
  /dev/fd/3 3< "$file2" /dev/fd/4 4< "$file1" >> "$file2"
```

If the lines are unique and you don't mind the output being sorted, you could also do:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -uo "$file2" "$file1" "$file2"
```

As to what's wrong in your code:

> ```
> FILE1=$1   
> FILE2=$2
> ```

all uppercase variables are by convention reserved for *environment* variables (variables exported to the environment which is a shared namespace), so it's good practice not to use all uppercase variables for mere shell variables.

> ```
> if [ ! -e "$FILE2" ]
> then
>    touch $FILE2
> fi
> ```

You quoted it in the arguments to `[`, but not to `touch`, why?

Also, note it's

```
touch "$file_or_option"
```

If you want the variable to always be treated as a file argument, you need:

```
touch -- "$file2"
```

Also the `if ! condition; then do-something-to-make-it-true` are often bad practice and subject to race condition. It's better to do `enforce-the-condition || die-if-couldn't`. So here:

```
touch -- "$file2" || exit
```

But anyway, the `>>` redirection will create the file (and return an error if it can't).

> ```
> while read line; do
> ```

When you start using loops in shells *especially `while read` loops*, then that generally means you're going for the wrong approach. You're going to run several commands sequentially for each line of a file, which is not how you do shell scripting. Instead, you want to run a few specialised commands once *cooperating* to the task.

First, to read a `line` in POSIX shells, the syntax is

```
IFS= read -r line
```

not
`read line`

> ```
>   if grep -q "$line" $FILE2
> ```

Again, it's:

```
grep -q "$option_or_regexp"
```

Or:

```
grep -q -- "$regexp"
```

Or:

```
grep -qe "$regexp"
```

If you want to search for strings instead of matching regexps, you need the `-F` option and if you want to match lines as a whole, you need `-x`. So:

```
grep -qxFe "$line" < "$file2"
```

> ```
>   then
>     echo
>   else
>     echo $line >> $FILE2
> ```

Again, you're applying the split+glob operator to the content of `$line` (and to `$FILE2` if using `bash` not in sh mode).

Also, `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data. You need:

```
printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$file2"
```

Here. But it's a waste to re-open `$file2` for each pass in the loop where you could have done it once for the whole loop.

> ```
>   fi
> done < $FILE1
> ```

Again:

```
done < "$file1"
```

if using `bash`.